# How to make ACL logic use OAuthToken model?

Tags: access-token, loopbackjs, strongloop

When loopback-component-oauth2 is used for implementation of oauth2 server, it makes special model to manage oauth2 token, named by `OAuthToken`. 
Once user is authenticated whatever authorization type is, a token is saved as instance of `OAuthToken` Model
But loopback's ACL uses 'AccessToken' model, which is inbuilt model of loopback module. 
So in this case, loopback's ACL doesn't work well because it searches request token from `AccessToken`, not `OAuthToken`.

Is there any way to change token model for ACL? How to make ACL search access token in `OAuthToken` model?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a TODO on our roadmap. See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/817.

BTW, the oAuth 2 authentication middleware will set the instance of OAuthToken into req.accessToken. Do you see any ACL code that checks the type of req.accessToken?

Comment: No, I don't. In my case, I solved the problem above by setting loopback oauth2 middleware first than loopback.rest(). But this works single process with oauth server and api server(resource server). If oauth server and api server is seperated, api server cannot find proper token instance because it try to search in `AccessToken` model, not `OAuthToken`. This makes ACL for $owner be failed.